# UPDATE Select Statement with Multiple Joins

Tags: sql-server-2005, join, sql-update

I am trying to update data in a `Contacts_CSTM` table based on data in a `Project_CSTM` table. This is the query I'm using, but I get an error:  "Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier"

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE Insurance_Check_Expiration
  @ID_C AS NVARCHAR (55) = ID_C
  AS
 BEGIN      
 SET NOCOUNT ON
 IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM CONTACTS_CSTM WHERE ID_C = @ID_c)

 Update contacts_cstm set insurance_expired_label_c = 'INSURANCE EXPIRED'
 WHERE DRIVERS_LICENSE_NUMBER_C IS NOT NULL AND @ID_C=
 (SELECT cc.id_c
 FROM PROJECT_CSTM PC 
 JOIN PROJECT P 
 ON P.ID = PC.ID_C
 JOIN PROJECT_RELATION PR
 ON PR.PROJECT_ID = P.ID  
 JOIN CONTACTS C
 ON C.ID = PR.RELATION_ID 
 JOIN CONTACTS_CSTM CC
 ON CC.ID_C = C.ID
 WHERE CC.ID_C = @ID_C AND INSURANCE_EXPIRED_C ='1')
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you are comparing a string value with a GUID... Can you show the columns used and their data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you're setting the value of @ID_C to a value (ID_C) which is obviously not a valid GUID.

This is the functional equivalent of what you did, run it and you'll get the same error.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Insurance_Check_Expiration
  @ID_C AS NVARCHAR (55) = ID_C
  AS
 BEGIN      
 DECLARE @A UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

 SET @A = @ID_C


 END

 exec Insurance_Check_Expiration
```

EDIT: Here's a functional example based on the OP's comments:

```
CREATE TABLE GUIDExample (ID_C UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
GO
CREATE PROC GuidExample_Insert @ID_C UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @ID_C
END
GO
CREATE TRIGGER GUID_Example ON GUIDExample
AFTER INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @ID_C UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

    SELECT @ID_C = ID_C
    FROM Inserted


    EXEC GuidExample_Insert @ID_C
GO

DECLARE @SampleGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

SET @SampleGUID = NEWID()

INSERT GUIDExample (ID_C)
VALUES(@SampleGUID)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Wil. I struggle w/ SQL, perhaps you can help me understand. How do I write the update statement so I only update the record that contains the ID of the record? Does that question make sense?

Comment: The proc is set up to take an input parameter. Change `@ID_C = ID_C` to `@ID_C` after `ALTER PROCEDURE` and make sure that a valid GUID is being passed into the procedure when calling. Your procedure call should look something like `EXEC Insurance_Check_Expiration 'The GUID You're Trying To Pass`. It might be a variable, it might be a parameter from an application, as long as it is a uniqueidentifier it'll work. Even better, change @ID_C from `NVARCHAR(55)` to `UNIQUEIDENTIFER` if that's what the value being passed into the proc actually is.

Comment: After Alter Procedure, I have @ID_C AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER. The EXEC Insurance_Check_Expiration is in the trigger, is that where I put EXEC Insurance_Check_Expiration @ID_C? I know I'm showing my ignorance, but you don't learn unless you ask questions, no matter how dumb they are. I appreiciate your help Wil

Comment: @Stan, if it is a trigger than you need to supply the proc with a value of some kind. If the trigger has a variable named @ID_C that gets populated with a value, then yes the procedure call would be `EXEC Insurance_Check_Expiration @ID_C`.

Comment: I see how that works... No more error. The insurance_expired_label_c field is still not being poplated, so I'll work on figuring that out. Thanks Wil

Comment: @Stan, cool. I just added a functional example of what I was talking about just in case.

Comment: I can't tell you how helpful this is... you've filled in a number of knowledge gaps. Thank you.